# Too much onion flavor in dip

Tags: onions

I've just made a cream cheese, mushroom and onion spread and the onion flavor is way too strong.  Is there any way I can reduce it by adding something?

Comment: Other than more cream cheese and mushrooms? There is no good onion flavor neutralizer, so dilution is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you would post a full recipe as that would eliminate fruitless suggestions. Two things come to mind:

- If the onions are included raw, you should wrap the chopped onions in a towel and wring the 'juice' out.
- Acid of some kind could help too, either exchange sour cream for the cream cheese or find a way to incorporate lemon/lime juice.

Comment: The question's about a dip that was already made, unfortunately.

Comment: Mm, understood. In that case the citrus juice suggestion still stands. I often find myself wondering what a dish needs only to discover it simply lacks acid.

Answer (score 1):

If the onions that were added were raw, this may sound weird, but try add a bit more onion that's been caramelized with extra sugar.

But I think Stranger's way of more cream cheese and mushroom is the safest.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and quickly blanch the onions before adding them to the dip. Blanching onions will reduce their sharpness.